# Mario Kart "mirror mode" - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, geometry, mirror

I am wondering about how the developers of games like Mario Kart go about switching the orientation of their levels. Is there an easy way to do this in OpenGL. For those who aren't aware, if you were to play a level in "mirror" mode, a door that is usually on the left would then be on the right.

Here is a small example

A polygon with these four verticies

```
X      Y


Z      W
```

Would be

```
Y      X


W      Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A polygon with these four verticies

You don't need that.

1. Set mirror transform matrix. Mirror matrix is the one that scales by negative value. `glScalef(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`, for example is x-axis mirror.
2. Call `glFrontFace` with `GL_CW`. I.e. change front face to "opposite" value.
3. Render scene.

Same principle can be used with 3.0 shaders, even if you'll have to use something else to build

```
-1 0 0 0 
 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1
```

Scale matrix

Although, yes, in case of video game it might be easier (collision detection) just to flip entire map in level editor and save it as new level instead of flipping it on the fly.

Comment: @Gigi: Irrelevant. The method is the same with shaders, regardless of what you use to make the matrix.

Comment: @Gigi: No matter what version of OpenGL you use, you use matrices to transform vertices. It is irrelevant for GL what your matrix represents - scale, rotation, translation, projection, identity, mirror, shadow - the only difference is their values, operations performed by GL do not change. OpenGL 3 and above still uses matrices in shaders. The only difference is that you load them with glUniformMatrix* instead of glLoadMatrix/glRotate/glTranslate/glScalef.